# Retrieve data from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter so I'm having some difficulties I want to retrieve data from the database and load it in the view but I couldn't figure out how.
Here is my model:

```
public function viewClientWaterwell(){
    $userid = get_client()->userid;
    $waterwells = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from($this->table)
        ->where('ww_client_id', $userid)
        ->get()->result_array();
    return $waterwells;
}
```

Here is my clientController:

```
    public function viewClient()
{
    $data['waterwells'] = $this->waterwell_model->viewClientWaterwell();
    $this->data($data);
    $this->view('waterwells/clients/viewClient');
    $this->layout();
}
```

I want to pass some data in a view to the client side but I can't figure out how. I think there is some problem with my model but I cannot figure out what. I'm new to this and will appreciate your feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use second argument to pass data to your template or view file

Here is example to start

Inside your controller function

```
public function viewClient()
{
   $data = array( 'myvar' => 'I love stackoverflow' );
   $this->load->view('waterwells/clients/viewClient', $data);
}
```

And inside your template or view file you can access them by their name.

```
<?php echo $myvar; ?>
```